# Why EfCore return null relation when use Include?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I Have ProductParam table with this Ralations and Two Table Product And Store that Product has one-to-many relation with store

```cs
public class ProductParam
{
    public int StoreId {get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int StoreId {get;set;}
    public List<ProductParam> ProductParams {get;set;}
}

public class Store
{
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
    public List<ProductParam> ProductParams {get;set;}
}
```

when i use this request

```cs
_context.ProductParam.Include(x => x.Product).ToList();
```

I get null value from include relation

Who help me ??

when i remove relation between Product and Store this problem solved.

Comment: Please edit your question and redact the text , that is not readable !

Comment: There is no `ProductParam.Product` property. We can't help you if your code isn't correct/complete.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to post a more complete example because the code you posted doesn't match your entities. (ProductParam doesn't have a Product navigation property)

Overall your entities look a bit buggered. ProductParam looks like a many-to-many joining table between Product and Store.

Product needs a PK, which I would assume is ProductId. It doesn't make much sense for it to have a StoreId if it has a collection of ProductParam, and it doesn't make sense for a store to have a collection of products and productparams.

If this is EF Core 5 or 6 you don't need to use a ProductParam entity in your navigation properties if you want a many-to-many relationship between products and stores. (each product has many stores, and each store has many products) You should be able to define your entities as:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    [Key]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This would require configuring the relationship in the DbContext OnModelCreating or via an EntityTypeConfig to tell EF about the ProductParam entity / table to use to resolve the relationship as part of a `.HasMany(x => x.Stores).WithMany(x => x.Products)` (configured from the Product side)  For this just do some checking on EF documentation for configuring Many-to-Many relationships for your target EF version.

For EF Core 3.1 and lower you would need to define and use the ProductParam entity and use those in the navigation properties:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductParam> ProductParams{ get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    [Key]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductParam> ProductParams{ get; set; }
}
```

Which is just messier when working with the relationships. This also applies to EF Core 5/6 if you want other specific properties to be part of the joining table. (other than just the Product and Store references)

Comment: I remove my answer because that you post is really better